# add @keyframes in in-line css instead of from a css file

Tags: html, css, frontend

how can one add @ keyframes in in-line css?

I have tried placing the keyframes in the style attribute but it did not work.

is there anyway by which this can be done ?

Comment: works fine in the style element (`<style></style>`). What you properly mean is within the style-attribute. It cant work there as `@keyframes` is not part of an element but an animation called out by an element.

Comment: Thanks for that i edited the question to attributes.

Answer (score 1):

**No**. since the animation is not declared in the element, it's only called upon it.

Comment: how ever inline animations are working ?

Comment: re-read what he said. An animation (@keyframes)  is not declared inside an element. `inline-css only declares for that specific element. As such you cannot use `@keyframes` there => does not work

Answer (score 0):

You can use **in-line css** in keyframes just omit the to or 100% declaration from the @keyframe.

```css
.progress-bar {
  border: 2px solid #53a2ed;
  border-radius: 14px;
}
.progress-bar > div { 
  color: white; 
  background: #53a2ed;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap; 
  padding: 10px 20px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  animation: progress-bar 2s;
}

@keyframes progress-bar {
   0% { width: 0; }
}
```

```html
<div class="progress-bar">
  <div style="width: 80%">80% complete</div>
</div>
```